# How to build and predict using decision tree in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

is there any way to build and predict using decision tree in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you cans see [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/28025/does-tensorflow-support-a-decision-tree-classifier) and [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12919/is-tensorflow-a-complete-machine-learning-library/) there is no way of using Decision Trees with Tensorflow (however Random Forests which consist of Decision Trees are supported). If you want to use Decision Trees definitely you better go with [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html).

Comment: The question is closed, but I thought I would just drop a link to the new [TensorFlow Decision Forests](http://tensorflow.org/decision_forests), in case someone came looking.

It should be easy to train a decision tree, random forest or gbdt there.